# If $a \leq b_{n} \leq c$ then $a \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (b_{n}) \leq c$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(b_n)$ be a convergent sequence such that $a \leq b_{n} \leq c$ for every $n$. Show that $$a \ \leq\ \lim_{n \to \infty } b_{n} \ \leq\ c$$

This is very similiar to the Squeeze theorem but I'm not sure if this is true since $a$ and $c$ are different constant sequences.

Comment: Hint: let $a_n=a,c_n=c$ and squeeze.

Comment: I guess that $(b_n)$ is assumed to be a convergent sequence..?

Comment: @Surb yes it is

Comment: This is true if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists. More generally, all accumulation points of the set $\{b_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ lie in the interval $[a,c]$.

Comment: @MPW This is why I showed it for $\limsup/\liminf$ in my answer.

Comment: @Surb: Understood

Answer (score 3):

Since $(b_n)$ is bounded, there exists $b_-$ and $b_+$ such that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} b_n = b_- \qquad \text{and}\qquad \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n = b_+.$$

Now suppose by contradiction that $b_-<a$, then there exists $N$ such that 
$$ |b_N-b_-|< \frac{b_--a}{2} \implies b_N<\frac{b_-+a}{2}<a \implies \text{contradiction}$$

Similarly, if $b_+>c$, then there exists $M$ such that 
$$ |b_M-b_+|< \frac{b_+-c}{2} \implies b_M>\frac{b_++c}{2}>c \implies \text{contradiction}$$

It follows that $$a\leq b_-\leq b_+\leq c$$
In particular, if $(b_n)$ is convergent, then $b_-=b_+$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $l := \lim_{n}b_{n}$. If $a > l$, then
$|b_{n}-l| < a-l$ for large $n$, implying $b_{n} - l < a - l$ for large $n$, implying $b_{n} < a$ for large $n$, a contradiction; if $c < l$, then likewise we have $c < b_{n}$ for large $n$, a contradiction again.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Intuitively, if the limit exceeds $c$, the sequence itself must eventually exceed $c$.

The rest is a matter of translating this to math.